# Leaving Breadcrumbs in Ansible doesn't work

Tags: linux, mysql, ansible

Following is the piece of code I implemented in Ansible, which tries to configure a MySQL replication:

```
- stat: path=/etc/mysql/ansible.repl
  register: check_sql_path

- name: create replicator user
  mysql_user:
    name: "replicator"
    host: "%"
    password: "{{ mypass.password_replication }}"
    priv: "*.*:REPLICATION SLAVE"
    state: present
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- mysql_replication:
    mode: changemaster
    master_host: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
    master_user: replicator
    master_password: "{{ mypass.password_replication }}"
  when: check_sql_path.stat.exists == false
  notify:
    - restart mysql

- command: touch /etc/mysql/repl.ansible
  when: check_sql_path.stat.exists == false
```

But before doing so, it checks if

```
check_sql_path.stat.exists is false
```

The variable `check_sql_path.stat.exists` is set to true when Ansible runs for the first time, so that second time Ansible is called, it doesn't execute this block of code.

But somehow this is executed during my second run and I get the following exception:

```
==> site: TASK [mysql_replication] *******************************************************
==> site: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "(1198, 'This operation cannot be performed with a running slave; run STOP SLAVE first'). Query == CHANGE MASTER TO ['MASTER_HOST=%(master_host)s', 'MASTER_USER=%(master_user)s', 'MASTER_PASSWORD=%(master_password)s']"}
==> site:   to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/ansible/playbook.retry
```

It looks like the `when` condition is not taken into consideration by Ansible.

I also checked the server and the file `/etc/mysql/ansible.repl` is created the first time.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the existence of `/etc/mysql/ansible.repl` and you are running `touch` command on `/etc/mysql/repl.ansible`. The file names are different.

To avoid mistakes use constants (defined as variables, possibly with meaningful names).

<sup>Also use consistent YAML syntax (i.e. do not mix `=` with `:`-style), and native modules (`file` instead of `command: touch`).</sup>

```
vars:
  mysql_repl_flag_path: /etc/mysql/ansible.repl

tasks:
  - stat:
      path: "{{ mysql_repl_flag_path }}"
    register: mysql_repl_flag

  # two tasks skipped for clarity

  - file:
      path: "{{ mysql_repl_flag_path }}"
      state: touch
    # because it is "touch" operation, the following condition is not necessary:
    # when: mysql_repl_flag.stat.exists == false
    # it also could be simpler:
    # when: not mysql_repl_flag.stat.exists
```